# How to integrate custom cordova(3.3) plugin into sencha app?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, cordova-3

We are trying to migrate our Android native app, well, actually some part of the platform to Sencha Touch + Cordova (3.3). First of all, we are trying to migrate the Connection Manager Service. This is a library inside the Android project which manages the connection with the server (queues, and data parsing) and it is running as a service.

So we would like to implement this library as a cordova plugin and then integrate it in the sencha project. I have been reading a lot of literature about this, but I can not find any solution similar to what I am looking for. The cordova plugins have a fixed structure (folders docs/src/test/www) but our plugin would use several libraries, and the source is more complex that this.

I found this project [Cordova Background Service plugin](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-sample) which I think that can be helpful, so I could use it as an example to build my own. Would it be a good idea to implement the service as a plugin? or should I try a different approach?

Once it is done, how could I import it into the Sencha project and use it? Is there any way to import it localy into Sencha?

I have been reading a lot of literature about it, but I couldn't find anything really helpful.

Thanks in advance.